# producer consumer using AutoReset Event in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading

Below code is not working usin Auto Reset event, what wrong i am doing ?

```
using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading;

    namespace Threaddd
    {
        class Program
        {
            static int num = 0;
            static EventWaitHandle e = new AutoResetEvent(false);
            static object o = new object();

            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                new Thread(Consumer).Start();
                new Thread(Producer).Start();

            }


            static void Producer()
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    if (num == 0)
                    {
                        num++;
                        Console.WriteLine("Produced " + num);
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);
                        e.Set();
                        e.WaitOne();

                    }
                }
            }

            static void Consumer()
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    if (num == 1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Consumed " + num);
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);
                        num--;
                        e.Set();
                        e.WaitOne();

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        e.WaitOne();
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: It always helps if you can give us an idea of what you are expecting the code to do.

Comment: As a sidenote, if you are using .NET 4, there are data structures that make life so much easier, one being the BlockingCollection http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx

Comment: You are using AutoResetEvent when Semaphore is available.

Comment: @ martin james, i was just experimenting ..... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like when the Producer thread calls e.Set(), it does not notify the Consumer thread immediately, so the Producer thread consumes the event when it calls e.WaitOne().

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx

"There is no guarantee that every call to the Set method will release a thread. If two     calls are too close together, so that the second call occurs before a thread has been released, only one thread is released. It is as if the second call did not happen. Also, if Set is called when there are no threads waiting and the AutoResetEvent is already signaled, the call has no effect."

One idea would be to use a separate event for each thread as the supplied link illustrates.

Comment: So it means, if producer thread calls e.set(); e.waithandle(); , e.set() may not be used to notify consumer thread instantly, but it may consumed by producer thread it self if i have called e.waithandle() on it. Interesting......... Thnks

Comment: Correct, a simple test to see would be to just have e.WaitOne() in the consumer and e.Set(); e.WaitOne(); in the producer, after a few runs, sometimes the Producer will Set and then consume the event in WaitOne before the consumer does

Answer (score 2):

This is not a real consumer / producer pattern implementation.
`e.Set()` will release only ONE thread that is waiting using `e.WaitOne()`

So, when you write:

```
e.Set();
e.WaitOne();
```

On the producer thread, you are actually not enabling the consumer thread to get the signal

Try the following:

```
        static void Producer()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Console.WriteLine("Produced " + num++);
                e.Set();
            }
        }

        static void Consumer()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                e.WaitOne();
                Console.WriteLine("Consumed " + num);
            }
        }
```

Comment: This will cause num to go larger than 1 in some cases. This will happen if the consumer thread gets paused for more than 1 second and set gets called when e is already set.

Comment: That is correct, I assumed @kamal added the num variable just for debug. What do you have to say about it @kamal?

Answer (score 1):

If your okay with your consumer and producer thread running wild you can simplify your program by removing some of the sets and waitones:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace Threaddd
{
internal class Program
{
    private static int num = 0;
    private static EventWaitHandle e = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    private static object o = new object();

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Thread(Consumer).Start();
        new Thread(Producer).Start();

    }


    private static void Producer()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (num == 0)
            {
                num++;
                Console.WriteLine("Produced " + num);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                e.Set();
            }
        }
    }

    private static void Consumer()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (num == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Consumed " + num);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                num--;
                e.WaitOne();
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

If that is not an option both your producer and consumer(s) must have their own events.

Comment: What happens in the consumer when num > 1? Note the if (num == 1).

Comment: @MartinBrown There is only one producer thread and it only increment num when it's equal to 0. So I'm not sure how it would get to be greater than 1.

Answer (score 1):

To keep num between 0 and 1 you can use the following pattern and lose the if statements:

```
   class Program
   {
      static volatile int num = 0;

      // Initialized set to ensure that the producer goes first.
      static EventWaitHandle consumed = new AutoResetEvent(true);

      // Initialized not set to ensure consumer waits until first producer run.
      static EventWaitHandle produced = new AutoResetEvent(false);

      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         new Thread(Consumer).Start();
         new Thread(Producer).Start();
      }

      static void Producer()
      {
         while (true)
         {
            consumed.WaitOne();
            num++;
            Console.WriteLine("Produced " + num);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            produced.Set();               
         }
      }

      static void Consumer()
      {
         while (true)
         {
            produced.WaitOne();
            Console.WriteLine("Consumed " + num);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            num--;
            consumed.Set();               
         }
      }
   }
```

It is worth pointing out that normally there is some kind of queue between the producer and the consumer so that the producer can create more than one item between each run of the consumer. The way I have written the above there is little point having the consumer and producer on separate threads as they will not be able to run at the same time.